# Очереди с приоритетом в C++

Tags: c++, очередь

Здравствуйте,мне нужна очередь с приоритетом,в которой лежат вершины.Каждая вершина описывается левым,правым потомком ,приоритетом и номером.В очереди с приоритетом должны происходить сравнения на основе приоритетов вершин.Скажие,пожалуйста,где моя ошибка в реализации?

Выдаёт ошибку 'cmp' does not name a type

```
struct Node
{
    int number = 0;
    int priority = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
};

int main(){
    auto cmp = [](Node a, Node b) { return a.priority  < b.priority ;};
    priority_queue<Node, deque<Node>, decltype(cmp) > q;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания экземпляра типа нужно вызывать конструктор, принимающий компаратор:

```
priority_queue<Node, deque<Node>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);
```

<kbd>[Тест](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97c8e9b956a399ad)</kbd>

Ошибка вида:

> error: 'cmp' does not name a type

[появляется](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/s7ighVwFUsNZIcg8), если не включена поддержка `c++11`. Нужно её включить соответствующими ключами компилятора.

Answer (score 3):

Ваша первая ошибка в том, что Вы не пишите в тексте вопроса, что за проблема у Вас возникла.

Ваша вторая ошибка в том, что Вы почему-то создаёте очередь из `int`'ов, когда Вам нужна очередь из `Node`'ов:

```
priority_queue<Node, deque<Node>, decltype(cmp) > q(cmp);
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку 'cmp' does not name a type @ixSci

Comment: @VladslavRublevskii, такой ошибки не должно быть, должна быть другая. Я поправил код.